# Backward variadic template

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I want to write a template function that does this (pseudo-code):

```
shift(T& a,T& b,T& c,...,T& y,const T& z) {
  a = b;
  b = c;
  ...
  y = z;
}
```

My attempt involved putting the variadic argument as the first argument as follows:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
inline void shift(A& a, const B& b) noexcept {
  a = b;
}
template<typename B, typename C, typename... AA>
inline void shift(AA&... aa, B& b, const C& c) noexcept {
  shift(aa...,b);
  shift(b,c);
}
```

Why doesn't this work? Can a variadic argument only be the last argument? Then is there a way to make the last reference constant?

I need a `const` reference for a case like:

```
double a, b, c;
shift(a,b,c,5);
```

**EDIT**:
Ok, this particular problem can of course be solved by reversing the order of the function arguments:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
inline void shift(const B& b, A& a) noexcept {
  a = b;
}
template<typename C, typename B, typename... AA>
inline void shift(const C& c, B& b, AA&... aa) noexcept {
  shift(b,aa...);
  b = c;
}
```

But I would still like to know if syntax allows for placing variadic arguments in any place other then the last and under what circumstances?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As T.C.'s comment below points out, in your first example `aa` is in a non-deduced context (14.8.2.5 p5 defines non-deduced contexts, including "a function parameter pack that does not occur at the end of the parameter-declaration-list") and so the parameter pack cannot be deduced.

> if syntax allows for placing variadic arguments in any place other then the last and under what circumstances?

In addition to the restriction stated above that caused problems for your first example, a template parameter pack has to be the last template parameter unless all following template parameters can be deduced. 14.1 [temp.param] p11:

> A template parameter pack of a function template shall not be followed
>   by another template parameter unless that template parameter can be deduced from the parameter-type-list of the function template or has a default argument (14.8.2).

So this is OK because both template parameter packs can be deduced independently from the function parameters:

```
template<typename... T, typename... U>
  void f(std::tuple<T...>, std::tuple<U...>)
  { }
```

A different way to write your `shift` function is to use an `index_sequence`

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template<typename... T, size_t... I>
void
shift_impl(std::tuple<T...> t, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
  // Use pack expansion with comma operator to populate unused array:
  int dummy[] = {
    (std::get<I>(t) = std::get<I+1>(t), 0)...
  };
}

template<typename T0, typename... T>
void
shift(T0&& arg0, T&&... args)
{
  shift_impl(std::tie(arg0, args...), std::index_sequence_for<T...>{});
}

int main()
{
  int i = 0, j = 1, k = 2;
  shift(i, j, k);
  std::cout << i << ' ' << j << ' ' << k << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Um, template parameter pack and function parameter pack are different things. `AA` is at the end of the template parameter list; `aa` isn't at the end of the parameter-declaration-list, making it a non-deduced context.

Comment: @T.C. in Jonathan's example, `T` is not at the end of its parameter list and it's a template parameter pack. But I can't see how that relates to the code in the question.

Comment: @ᐅJohannesSchaub-litbᐊ Sure. My point, when I wrote the comment, is that that quote ([temp.param]/11) doesn't apply to OP's example.

Comment: I don't know if I'm more impressed by the wittiness of the solution or that it actually makes sense. Nice use of the comma operator! There's always one questions I have with solutions like this one, do the `dummy` and the `integer_sequence` get optimized out?

Comment: @SU3, the `index_sequence` is just an empty struct so doesn't matter much either way. I would expect the whole `shift` function to be inlined and optimised away.  I've added another implementation without the array anyway.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I'm not sure about the second version - using `std::tie` loses the sequencing guarantee.

Answer (score 4):

[Full disclosure: I authored Hana]

I'm not trying to answer your original question, since Jonathan did that just fine.

However, if you're looking for a solution to your problem and if you have access to a bugfree C++14 compiler (hence Clang for now), you can use [Boost.Hana](https://github.com/boostorg/hana). Hana is a modern metaprogramming library that enables you to metaprogram while keeping a high level of abstraction. Hence, you can write what you need in a readable way, instead of having to know about all the dirty tricks of the language. The library takes care of that for you:

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <functional> // for std::ref
#include <iostream>
namespace hana = boost::hana;

template <typename T0, typename ...T>
void shift(T0&& t0, T&& ...ts) {
    auto args = hana::make_tuple(std::ref(t0), std::ref(ts)...);
    hana::for_each(hana::range_c<int, 0, sizeof...(ts)>, [&](auto i) {
        args[i].get() = args[i + hana::int_c<1>].get();
    });
}

int main() {
    int i = 0, j = 1, k = 2;
    shift(i, j, k);
    std::cout << i << ' ' << j << ' ' << k << '\n';
}
```